# Cancel button not visible in google sign in framework for iOS

Tags: ios, google-plus, google-signin

This question might be very trivial but this is giving me headache since past 6 hours. I have integrated google sign in SDK for iOS in my project and everything seems to be working fine except for the cancel button. [image].

This screen comes up when i click on the google button in my login screen. But there is no way to dismiss this if the user decides to cancel google login. Typically the cancel button should come in the place of left bar button item but in this case  it is missing.

What am i doing wrong here??

Comment: Check if it is redirecting to Safari then you have to implement a lot of code. Also Apple rejects Google Sign In featured App if it redirects to safari.

Comment: This is the latest google sign in SDK and it wont redirect to safari. instead it opens a screen like this with in the app itself...

Comment: Good to know.. Google Provide all header files as opens source as well, you can always edit whatever you want.

Comment: really weird, I have the same issue :(

Comment: @GenosseWu : I have removed all the google sdk files from my project and integrated them from scratch again and then it worked for me..

Comment: thanks I'll also try.

Comment: unfortunately I did that but the cancel button is still not visible, any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any UIAppearance configurations in your AppDelegate? Maybe the bar color is the same as the button text color. I solved the issue by setting up the global defaults for most of the relevant properties exposed by the `UINavigationbar.appearance()` proxy in my `AppDelegate.swift` file (should be similar for ObjC)

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.42, blue:0.90, alpha:1.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will be getting cancel button only in two cases :

1 - If you have already enter google username and password in this screen and moved to next.

2 - If you have google plus app installed and already logged in.

In current case, you wont be getting cancel button as its a webview.
So solution is that you need to create your own back button.

Create a bar button item and assign it to leftBarButtonItem of navigationItem.
Put this code in `viewDidLoad`

```
    UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"CancelImage" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton setContentEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -15, 0, 0)];
        [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backToHOmePage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        UIBarButtonItem *customBackBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myButton];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBackBtn;
```

Then create backToHomePageMethod -

```
-(void)backToHOmePage
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting `GoogleSignIn.framework` and
`GoogleSignIn.bundle` files and adding them back.

Also, make sure you have added `GoogleSignIn.bundle` to your Xcode project's Copy Bundle Resources build phase (Go to Targets > YourProject > Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources and add `GoogleSignIn.bundle`).